# Django: disable error messages for required field on initial form view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a Django form that looks like this and allows users to make a choice:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    candidate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes',), (False, 'No',))
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

The template looks like this:

```
    <form id="pledge" action="/pledge" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ form.choice_field.errors }}
            {{ form.choice_field }}
        </div>
        {{ form.candidate }}
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit your response</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My view is like this:

```
def pledge(request, candidate_hashkey=None):
    candidate = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # process input
    else:
        candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pledge_hashkey=candidate_hashkey)
        form = PledgeForm({'candidate': candidate_hashkey})
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'candidate': candidate
    }
    return render(request, 'frontend/pledge.html', context)
```

The problem is that on the initial GET view, before the user chooses anything, the form appears with an error at the top: "This value is required".

How can I disable this for the initial view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are bounding `PledgeForm` with data that's why you are seeing the error messages:

```
form = PledgeForm({'candidate': candidate_hashkey})
```

You should not bound the form with data:

```
form = PledgeForm()
```

P.S Although you say your form is `ChoiceForm` but in view you are using `PledgeForm`, but my answer might give you hints anyway.

Comment: @Alasdair's solution below is the appropriate route if you _do_ want to pre-populate the form with initial data

Answer (score 2):

For the GET request, you could use `initial`. This means the form is unbound so it won't be validated.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # process input
else:
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pledge_hashkey=candidate_hashkey)
    form = PledgeForm(initial={'candidate': candidate_hashkey})
```

However, it might be easier to remove the `candidate` field from the form entirely. To do this, you'll have to keep the hash in the URL (instead of `action="/pledge"` which appears to remove it).

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = ((True, 'Yes',), (False, 'No',))
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Then set the `candidate` field when you save the form:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pledge_hashkey=candidate_hashkey)
        obj.candidate = candidate
        obj.save()
        ...
```